NextAuth.js Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User')
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import Credentials from "next-auth/providers/credentials"
// Your own logic for dealing with plaintext password strings; be careful!
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
// import dbConnect from "./lib/dbConnect"; 
import UserModel from "./model/user";
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter"
import client from "./lib/db";

export const { handlers, signIn, signOut, auth } = NextAuth({
  adapter: MongoDBAdapter(client),

  providers: [
    Credentials({
      // You can specify which fields should be submitted, by adding keys to the `credentials` object.
      // e.g. domain, username, password, 2FA token, etc.
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "text", placeholder: "example@example.com" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "password" },
      },


      authorize: async (credentials) => {
        let user = null;

    // Check if user exists
    user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: credentials.email });

    if (!user) {
        // User not found, could proceed with registration logic here if needed
        throw new Error("User not found.");
    }

    // Verify the password using bcrypt
    const isPasswordValid = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password , user.passwordHash);
    
    if (!isPasswordValid) {
        throw new Error("Invalid password.");
    }

    // Return user object with their profile data (excluding password)
    return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
})

I'm working in auth.js. This code is giving me TypeError - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User') when I remove the function await UserModel.findOne everything is all right
also I'm not able to understand how to differentiate credentials of signup and signin different
I'm working in auth.js and it's documentation is very overwhelming for me.
Can anyone suggest some other documentation or youtube tutorial in hindi, which help me in understanding this library faster. I want to create a signup form like where the user can signin from facebook google or manually but this library sucks
